# What is different between save(), create() function in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to know what is the difference of `save()` and `create()` function in laravel 5. 
Where we can use `save()` and `create()` ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Model::create` is a simple wrapper around `$model = new MyModel(); $model->save()`
See the implementation

```
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return static
 */
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);

    $model->save();

    return $model;
}
```

**save()**

- save() method is used both for saving new model, and updating
  existing one. here you are creating new model or find existing one,
  setting its properties one by one and finally saves in database.
- save() accepts a full Eloquent model instance

  ```
  $comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

  $post = App\Post::find(1);

  $post->comments()->save($comment);
  ```

**create()**

- while in creating method you are passing an array, setting properties in
  model and persists in the database in one shot.
- create() accepts a plain
  PHP array

  ```
  $post = App\Post::find(1);

  $comment = $post->comments()->create([
      'message' => 'A new comment.',
  ]);
  ```

  **EDIT**
  As @PawelMysior pointed out, before using the create method, be sure to mark columns whose values are safe to set via mass-assignment (such as name, birth_date, and so on.), we need to update our Eloquent models by providing a new property called $fillable. This is simply an array containing the names of the attributes that are safe to set via mass assignment:

example:-

```
class Country extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'area',
        'language',
        ];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but can you please give me more elaboration. I was gone through the Laravel document but I didn't get much idea from there.

Comment: One important thing to note here: if you plan to use `create()`, all the attributes that you pass to it have to be listed in the `$fillable` attribute on the model. See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @PawelMysior so `create()` more secure than `save()`?

Comment: @YousefAltaf I can say both are secure, but create() is more flexible