# Eloquent create blank entries

Tags: mysql, eloquent, lumen

I am doing my first steps with Lumen (5.4) and i want store a data array into database. So, i have:

**MySQL rate_plans table**

```
id PK AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(45) NOT_NULL
slug VARCHAR(45) NOT_NULL
price FLOAT(5,2) NOT_NULL
created_at DATETIME NOT_NULL
updated_at DATETIME NOT_NULL
```

**Eloquent model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class RatePlan extends Model {

    protected $table = 'rate_plans';

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price'];

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

The problem is, Eloquent create the record with correct values for id, created_at and updated_at properties. But, name, slug are empty and price is 0.00. The code is:

```
$data = ['name' => 'Test', price => 99.99];
$model = new \App\Models\RatePlan();
$model->fill($data);
$model->slug = 'test';
$model->status = 'active';
$model->create();
```

Any ideas ? Why Eloquent doesn't fail on persist null values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel there are two methods for creating related models ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models))

- create()
- save()

You could use either one of them. To see the difference between both methods please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843202/what-is-different-between-save-create-function-in-laravel-5/38843288)

In your code either you could change it like this

```
$data = ['name' => 'Test', price => 99.99];
$model = new \App\Models\RatePlan();
$model->fill($data);
$model->slug = 'test';
$model->status = 'active';
$model->save();
```

Or you could pass value for `slug` in the `$data` array and proceed like this:

```
$data = [name => 'Test', slug => 'test',price => 99.99];

$model = new \App\Models\RatePlan();
$model->create($data);
```