# What is different between create(), insert(), save() function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to know what is the difference of `create()`, `insert()` and `save()` function in laravel. where we can use `create()`, `insert()` and `save()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is different between save(), create() function in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843202/what-is-different-between-save-create-function-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

The post [What is different between save(), create() function in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843202/what-is-different-between-save-create-function-in-laravel-5) explains very well the differences between `save()` and `create()` methods.

As for the `insert()` this belongs to Query Builder so you don't use the Laravel Eloquent.

The `insert()` method accepts an array of column names and values according to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements) and each array represents a record that should be inserted into the table.

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'picard@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'janeway@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
]);
```