# Inserting data into laravel db

Tags: php, laravel

I know that data can be inserted into the database in
Method 1:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the request...

    $flight = new Flight;

    $flight->name = $request->name;

    $flight->save();
}
```

Method 2:

```
$flight = Flight::create([
    'name' => 'London to Paris',
]);
```

What is the best way to use when inserting 1 value? What is the best way to use when you need to insert, say, 10 values? And are there any other better ways to insert values?

Comment: Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843202/what-is-different-between-save-create-function-in-laravel-5  and also if you are $request->all() keys matching database table column then you can use $flight = Flight::create($request->except('_token'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, there isn't much difference, but the main thing about `create` is that it has **mass assignment** related issues.

What it means is that, for example if you have a model `User` which has certain fields including a `role` field which can be `user` or `admin`.

Then if you create a new record using `create` method like this:

```php
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

then the member can pass the parameter `role` in request inputs and change his/her own role and get admin privileges, simple as that! You can prevent this with the property `$fillable` inside your models, but if it is not taken care of properly it will lead to these kind of issues.

One another point is that, the `create` method uses the `save()` itself, if you look at its implementation you can see this:

```php
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```